# Is there a tool to lookup all instances in the Bible where a particular verb is used with a certain stem, type, person, gender, or number?

Tags: hebrew

Using the Blue Letter Bible I can look at a particular verb, let’s say H559, and see every verse where that verb is used.

But, what I would like is a way to find every instance where a particular verb is used with masculine gender, or qal stem with feminine gender, or qal stem and imperfect type and 3rd person and singular number (but any gender). Is there a tool that enables this sort of search?

I’m imagining a tool where I can select a particular verb (maybe type in the strong’s number), then from drop downs I can select any combination of stem, gender, etc. and see a list of every verse where that verb appears with that combination of parsing.

Comment: See for the example of "mongenes" https://biblehub.com/greek/3439.htm which gives all the instances of a word and the corresponding part of speech

Comment: This question really belongs on (say) the meta site or somewhere else.

Comment: Logos Bible Software can do this.  Most advanced original language Bible Software can do this.  It may not be trivial to set up the search.

Comment: I don't know of a list to ask this question.  The Linguistics site doesn't seem to like this kind of question.

Comment: You could ask how to do this on the support groups for the different Bible software and see what is involved with each.

Comment: Is there a meta Biblical Hermeneutics site? I looked through all the other stackexchange sites and this site seemed like the closest fit (or the place where people who most likely know the answer would be). I'm surprised there doesn't appear to be a simple tool to do this. It seems like such a simple and obvious thing to build (though, I am a programmer, so maybe non-programmers wouldn't think this is simple). Maybe I will have to build it. I could start with the data at https://hb.openscriptures.org/ unless someone knows of a better source.

Comment: Logos allows you to do this. Olive tree bible app also allows you to do this if you download and pay for an interlinear bible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there doesn't appear to be a tool to do what I wanted, this is how I solved my issue for anyone following after me.

1. I checked out this [git repository](https://github.com/openscriptures/morphhb)
2. I ran the Perl command on that repository's index.html file:

   ```
   perl morphhbXML-to-JSON.pl --stripPointing --removeLemmaTypes --prefixLemmasWithH --remapVerses
   ```

This created a JSON file named "hebrew.json" in the same directory as the morphhb/index.html file.

3. I wrote a node application that imports the JSON file, parses it, loops over each book in the object, loops over each chapter in each book, loops over each verse in each chapter, loops over each word in each verse.
4. Finally, I did:

   ```
    const hebrew_full = word_array[0];
    const strong_full = word_array[1];
    const morph_full = word_array[2];
    if(morph_full.includes("HV")){
      let morph = morph_full.split("/")[0];
      let hebrew = hebrew_full.split("/")[0];
      let strong = strong_full.split(" ")[0];

      let morph_array = morph.split("");
      let word_object = {"hebrew":hebrew
         ,"strong":strong
         ,"morph":morph
         ,"verse":`${book_string} ${chapter_number+1}:${verse_number+1}`
         ,"language":morph_array[0]
         ,"part":morph_array[1]
         ,"stem":morph_array[2]
         ,"type":morph_array[3]
         ,"person":morph_array[4]
         ,"gender":morph_array[5]
         ,"number":morph_array[6]
         ,"state":morph_array[7]
      };
      myApp.morph_array.push(word_object);
   }
   ```
5. After this ran over the entire Bible JSON file (took about 1 millisecond) I was able to do something like:

   let result = myApp.morph_array.filter(function(v, i) {
   return (v.strong === "1254"
   && v.stem === "q"
   && v.type === "p"
   && v.person === "3"
   && v.gender === "m"
   && v.number === "s"
   );
   });

   console.log(result.map(a => a.verse));

and it returned

```
    [
  'Genesis 1:1',
  'Genesis 1:27',
  'Genesis 1:27',
  'Genesis 2:3',
  'Genesis 5:2',
  'Deuteronomy 4:32',
  'Isaiah 40:26',
  'Isaiah 41:20',
  'Isaiah 45:18',
  'Jeremiah 31:22',
  'Malachi 2:10'
]
```

The next step is to put an interface on the front of this, but this gets me far enough along to be useful for my own purposes.

Comment: Congratulations on getting it to work! Now, if you can find a way to create a user-friendly app using this feature, we all can benefit! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The logos Bible software is free and the basic word search includes in the free version. You can search for specific forms of words in it from drop down suggestions or using a double "quote". Its display is also perfect which shows alignment of English versions in it.

But for your basic word search you can find this on various sites with searching for the exact word "form" and you will get only those results. From biblehub to softwares like theword.net and MyBible for mobile. But drop down detailed view comes only in logos which is the best one. It comes with SBLGreek version and LEB and ASV and KJV in the free version.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying about searching for the exact word form, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for a tool where I do not have to know the form to begin with. I can just give it the strong's number and morphology information (stem, type, person, gender, number, and state) and it will show me any verses that contain that strong's number with those morphology constraints, without my having to know what the "exact word form" is.

Comment: That is not possible in any software coz you're expecting that you don't even know the language. However you can search by strong number in theword software, it will give you all the instances of occurrence. Then you can check the morphological form you want.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing my own code to do what I wanted to do since the tool I'm looking for doesn't seem to exist. I added an answer so other people can see what I did.

Comment: You should simply learn the languages rather than searching like that. Original language cannot replace such searches

Comment: I already know Hebrew (I spent 4 years studying it in college - I probably took the highest level class 6 times - we did different books each semester). I'm not trying to learn Hebrew, I'm trying to do research and was looking for a tool to make the research easier. Since the tool doesn't seem to exist I just built my own. That turned out to be trivial to do because the openscriptures project already had all the data in an easy to process format.

Comment: that's great. Perhaps you should make your own software a freeware like theword, or join theword. There is a great need to have the syntax search feature which is only available on Logos premium. The opentext site will provide the phrase or syntax search perhaps in future http://opentext.org/tools.html It's work in progress right now there.

Comment: @irrational,  Logos does allow you to do what you are asking. It works in the search bar. For example, you can write "lemma:θεός@" and after you type the @ symbol it gives you options to specify what part of speech you are looking for. I'm using Logos version 9